# how to add google analytics in same ng-click

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```
    <a id="msignup" href="#" ng-click="vm.authenticate('google'); ga('send', 'event', 'Sign up', 'click','signed in to receiptME');">Sign Up</a>
        <a id="mlogin" href="#" ng-click="vm.authenticate('google');ga('send', 'event', 'Login', 'click','Logged in to receiptME');">Login</a>
```

what is the alternative for the above code for event tracking

i have added the event tracking of google analytics in the above shown way .is there is any other way to do that event tracking

Comment: I wouldn't clutter up your view like that. Write a controller method and call that controller method with the `ng-click`, instead of putting all the google analytics stuff in your view like that.

Comment: is the above mentioned code is work or not can you tell me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should be like this.

```
<a id="msignup" href="#" ng-click="track('Sign up')">Sign Up</a>
<a id="mlogin" href="#" ng-click="track('Login')">Login</a>
```

When either one is clicked, it will call the function in your Controller, which should have something like this.

```
$scope.track = function(activity){
    vm.authenticate('google');
    var log = '';
    if (activity == 'Sign up'){
        log = 'signed in to receiptME';
    }
    else if (activity == 'Login')){
        log = 'Logged in to receiptME';
    }
    ga('send', 'event', activity, 'click', log);
}
```

Now if your original code works for you then this should be what you might want to consider doing instead.